# How to center the text of a label made with geom_label() whose vertical position was changed with vjust? (ggplot2 package)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, position

I plotted columns with the `ggplot2` package and the `geom_col()` function. I put a label at the top of each column with the respective values with the `geom_label()` function. Inside the `geom_label()` function I modified the text size (`size = 3`) and label position (`vjust = -1`), but the result showed the label in the desired position but with the text off-center.

How can I fix this issue?

```
library(ggplot2)

Factor <- c('A', 'B')
Y <- c(5, 10)

DF <- data.frame(Factor, Y)

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = Factor,
           y = Y)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = Y),
             vjust = -1,
             size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shifting the labels via `vjust` (or hjust) I would suggest to make use of `nudge_y`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Factor <- c('A', 'B')
Y <- c(5, 10)

DF <- data.frame(Factor, Y)

p <- ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = Factor,
           y = Y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 15))

p + geom_label(aes(label = Y), nudge_y = 1, size = 3)
```

[image]

A second option would be to make use of `ggtext::geom_richtext` which allows to add some margin between the data point and the label:

```r
p + ggtext::geom_richtext(aes(label = Y), vjust = 0, size = 3, label.margin = unit(5, "pt"))
```

[image]